# Group by multiple columns and separate

Tags: mysql, group-by

How to Group by multiple columns and separate below:

```
SELECT unit_id, status_engine, created_at FROM positions
```

it will result :

```
"unit_id","status_engine","created_at"
437,1,"06/20/2015 00:00:09"
437,1,"06/20/2015 00:01:09"
425,1,"06/20/2015 00:01:12"
425,1,"06/20/2015 00:01:17"
437,1,"06/20/2015 00:01:22"
425,1,"06/20/2015 00:01:27"
425,0,"06/20/2015 00:02:51"
437,1,"06/20/2015 00:03:13"
425,0,"06/20/2015 00:03:24"
425,0,"06/20/2015 00:03:30"
425,1,"06/20/2015 00:03:34"
425,1,"06/20/2015 00:05:48"
425,0,"06/20/2015 00:06:00"
425,0,"06/20/2015 00:12:04"    
425,1,"06/20/2015 00:14:00"
425,1,"06/20/2015 00:14:30"    
444,0,"06/20/2015 00:19:45"
425,1,"06/20/2015 00:19:47"
425,1,"06/20/2015 00:20:17"
437,0,"06/20/2015 00:21:01"
437,0,"06/20/2015 00:22:01"
```

I want to group unit ID and Status Engine, If Unit ID and status engine still be same, it not create new row. But if Unit ID same and status engine changed, it will create new row. Or if Unit ID not same, it will create new row.

Basically, if one of Unit ID or Status Engine changed, it will create new row. The purpose is to avoid same data Unit ID and Status Engine like data before.

I have used this query :

```
SELECT   gn,
         unit_id,
         status_engine,
         created_at
    FROM (            SELECT @r :=
                                  @r
                                + (@status_engine != status_engine OR @unit_id != unit_id)
                                AS gn,
                             @status_engine := status_engine AS sn,
                             @unit_id := unit_id AS ui,
                             s.unit_id,
                             s.status_engine,
                             s.created_at,
                             s.id                             
                        FROM (            SELECT @r := 0, @status_engine := 0, @unit_id := 0)
                             vars,
                             positions s
                       WHERE created_at BETWEEN start_date
                                            AND end_date
                    ORDER BY unit_id, created_at) al
GROUP BY gn;

"gn","unit_id","status_engine","created_at"
1,437,1,"06/20/2015 00:00:09"
2,425,1,"06/20/2015 00:01:12"
3,425,0,"06/20/2015 00:02:51"
4,425,1,"06/20/2015 00:03:34"
5,425,0,"06/20/2015 00:06:00"
6,425,1,"06/20/2015 00:14:00"
7,444,0,"06/20/2015 00:19:45"
8,437,0,"06/20/2015 00:21:01"
```

I have use but it too long processed:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT @r := @r + (@status_engine != status_engine) AS gn,
                   @status_engine := status_engine AS sn,
                   s.id,
                   s.unit_id,
                   s.status_engine,
                   s.created_at
              FROM (SELECT @r := 0, @status_engine := 0) vars, positions s
           ORDER BY unit_id, created_at) v GROUP BY gn
```

I want to store it as procedure in MySQL and call with event every 1 minutes with:

```
CREATE EVENT database.event_event
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY "1" MINUTE
STARTS '2015-06-25 19:08:10'

ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT ''
DO
BEGIN
CALL report_event(  DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) , NOW()  );
END
```

I was created table event for store this data with add INSERT INTO event (unit_id, status_engine, created_at), but result in table event still produce same data unit_id and status_engine with data before.

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your desired output.

Comment: @PM77-1 - it looks like he's trying to determine "runs" of a given set of values.